# Separation of a splited string

Tags: python

```
def getOnlyNames(unfilteredString):
    unfilteredString = unfilteredString[unfilteredString.index(":"):]
    NamesandNumbers = [item.strip() for item in unfilteredString.split(';')]
    OnlyNames = []

    for i in len(productsPrices):
        x = [item.strip() for item in productsPrices[i].split(',')]
        products.append(x[0])
    return products
```

So I'm trying to make a function that will separate a following string

```
 "Cars: Mazda 3,30000;     Mazda 5, 49900;"
```

So I will get only:

```
Mazda 3,Mazda 5
```

First I was removing the :

then I try to get only the name of the car without the price of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Cars: Mazda 3,30000;     Mazda 5, 49900;"
```

- split on the colon

  - ```
    ['Cars', ' Mazda 3,30000;     Mazda 5, 49900;']
    ```
- split the last item on the semicolon

  - ```
    [' Mazda 3,30000', '     Mazda 5, 49900', '']
    ```
- split the first two items on the comma.

  - ```
    [' Mazda 3', '30000'], ['     Mazda 5', ' 49900']
    ```
- take the first item of each and strip the whitespace

  - ```
    'Mazda 3'
    ```
  - ```
    'Mazda 5'
    ```

Comment: `[i.rpartition(':')[2].partition(',')[0].strip() for i in s.strip(';').split(';')]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for this:

```
import re
>>> s = "Cars: Mazda 3,30000; Mazda 5, 49900;"
>>> re.findall("[:;]\W*([^:;]*?)(?:,)", s)
['Mazda 3', 'Mazda 5']
>>> s = "Mazda 3, 35000; Cars: Mazda 4,30000;     Mazda 5, 49900;"
>>> re.findall("[:;]\W*([^:;]*?)(?:,)", s)
['Mazda 4', 'Mazda 5']
```

Comment: why can't the regex pattern simply be "**[:;](.*?),**" ??

Comment: This answer will fail with an example like `s = "Mazda 4, 35000; Cars: Mazda 3,30000;     Mazda 5, 49900;"`.